# How to take requested data as json object in django views?

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm submitting my form from postman. But i'm getting all key values as a list. I don't know why, how can i get key values without list.
here is request.data i'm getting:

```
{'from_email': ['somemail@gmail.com'], 'to_email': ['somemailother@gmail.com'], 'subject': ['hey man whats up ?'], 'html_body': [<InMemoryUploadedFile: email_test_template.html (text/html)>]}
```

I'm expecting it to be like following.

```
{'from_email': 'somemail@gmail.com', 'to_email': 'somemailother@gmail.com', 'subject': 'hey man whats up ?', 'html_body': <InMemoryUploadedFile: email_test_template.html (text/html)>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write simple loop over it,

```
response = {'from_email': ['a@gmail.com'], 'to_email': ['b@gmail.com'], 'subject': ['hey man whats up ?'], 'html_body': ['seom']}

dummy = dict()
for key, val in response.items():
    dummy[key] = val[0]


print(dummy)

{'from_email': 'a@gmail.com', 'to_email': 'b@gmail.com', 'subject': 'hey man whats up ?', 'html_body': 'seom'}
```

Comment: it worked, thank You. Can you remove mentioned emails from your answer.